# Why does Shurelia appear in Misha's and Aurica's Cosmosphere's?

Tags: ar-tonelico

In *Ar Tonelico: Melody of Elemia* in both Misha's and Aurica's Cosmospheres a girl with white hair appears

- In Level 4 of Aurica's Cosmosphere where she appear as Rei-chan
- In Level 4 of Misha's Cosmosphere where she appears as Misha's Mother
- In Levels 5 and 7 she appears as Misha's Sister

In Stage 3 we find out that the girl seen in Aurica's and Misha's Cosmospheres have to be Shurelia as they have the same hair style and also in Shurelia's Virtual World she looks the exact same as Misha's sister

Now i could understand why she would appear in Misha's Cosmosphere if the 2 met before Misha became the Star Singer must like how Harmonica appears in Misha's Cosmosphere but not in Aurica's, but Aurica had never met Shurelia before and even thought she was a robot (up until Mir's 3rd attack). while the Cosmosphere is also a mechanic of the game to Develop Misha and Aurica, both have to have passed Level 4 in order to be installed with Purger so regardless of route or personal choice the player will see Shurelia not wearing LINKER as apart of the story.

So why was Shurelia appearing in both of their Cosmospheres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Shurelia's will and personality can subconsciously seep in trace amounts into the other Reyvateils' Cosmospheres due to her being the Tower Administrator and residing into the Tower's Binary Field.

That said, she herself can't consciously see the events taking place in the Cosmospheres or interfere in them because her SH Server (the storage device where the Cosmospheres are lodged) is separate from Beta-6D's, which is the one where all other Reyvateils have their minds stored. And since the Beta-6D SH Server was added after her Administrator training was complete, she doesn't have any power to interfere with it either

(Reference: http://artonelico.wikia.com/wiki/ARM_Backup/Ar_Portal_translation/Toukousphere/Issue_46)