# Why does Mir appear inside Cloche's Cosmosphere

Tags: ar-tonelico

According to [This answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/23806/1587) there is a special reason why Shurelia is able to appear in Misha's and Aurica's Cosmospheres.

How in in the 4th Level of Cloche's Cosmosphere Mir appeared despite the 2 never having met. even if the reason for Shurelia appearing in other's Cosmospheres rings true for Mir according to [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/27305/1587)

> Cocona is also an IPD, meaning she does not connect to the "correct" server, but to the Infel Phira server.

this means IPDs have a totally different server that they connect to plus Infel Pira was man made after the Reyvateils appeared (as Infel, a Reyvateil herself, made it to prepare to sing Metafalica)

So i am wondering how is Mir turning up in Cloche's Cosmosphere?

Comment: minor question about Ar-tonelico. I played the game melody of metafalica on ps2. Is the anime and manga a creation off of the game? Or is the other way around? I see a few of these questions on here and it's got me interested.

Comment: The manga and the OVA are both spin-offs from the game, but only the manga from the first game is considered canon. The OVA and the second game's manga are heavily condensed retellings that even break canon.

Answer (score 1):

The servers can connect to each other to make the singing of Dual Songs and such possible, and there are some songs that depend on these connection to even be executed, so it's not unlikely that part of Mir's feelings ended up getting into Infel Phira during the time she and Loude were doing research on it.